# Cannot Connect to the Machine Translation Service

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, variations, connection, machine-translation

I have created my Machine Translation service and was able to start the service without any error. However, when I am trying to create or configure a Variation label and reach the 3rd step **Translation Options**, I get an error.

> Cannot connect to the Machine Translation Service, contact your site administrator
>   [image]

[image]

Comment: Check this **[SharePoint 2019: Cannot connect to the Machine Translation Service, contact your site administrator](https://debug.to/2572/cannot-connect-to-the-machine-translation-service-contact-your-site-administrator)**

Answer (score 2):

The timer job related to machine translation service may not be able accept or reply the request of IIS. Io resolve the issue you have to try the two following steps:

1. Try by stop and start machine translation service in the central admin

if this does not resolve your problem.

2. IISRESET and check the variation log will be enabled

Answer (score 1):

Check the below tech-net fro troubleshooting the Machine Translation services.

Did you try to stop and start the MTS service?

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj729796(v=office.15).aspx#TransServ](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj729796%28v=office.15%29.aspx#TransServ)

Comment: Yes, I did. I even recreated my MTS but no luck

Answer (score 0):

You need to "Configure service application associations"[image]

**default Application Proxy Group**

[image]